# Understand error function's return value type

Tags: haskell

```
:t error
```

shows,

```
error :: [Char] -> a
```

To understand, what is the type of a, i wrote this test code,

```
import Data.Typeable
custom = error "hello how are you"

main = do
  let a = custom
  putStrLn $ show (typeOf a)
```

It gets `error` function's return value and tries to print it using `show`
function.
It throws error as,

```
ab.hs:6:20:
    No instance for (Typeable a0) arising from a use of ‘typeOf’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable ()
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Typeable.Internal’
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable Bool
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Typeable.Internal’
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable Char
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Typeable.Internal’
      ...plus 14 others
```

How can i do `typeOf` for a variable and print it in string form?

Answer (score 4):

`a` is lower case, which means it's a type variable. It can take on any type. You can substitute the result of `error` for any expression and your code will type check. This is useful for partial functions, which aren't defined for all possible arguments. For example:

```
head :: [a] -> a
head [] = error "empty list"
head (x:_) = x
```

Given an empty list, you can't actually produce the first element because it doesn't exist. `error` makes the types work out, but blows up at runtime when evaluated.

Per [user5402's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646633/understand-error-functions-return-value-type/31646826#comment51239982_31646826) below:

> `error "add"` can have any type in part because it never returns.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to point out that `error "add"` can have any type in part because it never returns. The same can be said for the infinite loop `foo = foo` which is also how `undefined` is defined.

Comment: I think the standard allows for it to be, well, undefined, but in GHC base, `undefined` is [defined as](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Err.html#undefined) `undefined =  error "Prelude.undefined"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `typeOf` with a polymorphic expression, both because that would be impossible to type in Haskell and because there's no `TypeRep` representing type variables. Of course the latter would be easy enough to fix if it were possible to define `typeOf` in a way that could ever produce a type variable as its result, which it's not.

Note that if `typeOf` could represent type variables and accept polymorphic arguments, `typeOf (error "")` would simply print something like "a" or "forall a. a", so I'm not sure that that would help you.

In order to use `typeOf` on `error`, you'll have to give it a monomorphic type like this `typeOf (error "" :: String)` or `typeOf (error "" :: Int)`, which will print "String" and "Int" respectively.

Comment: `typeOf` and its associated class `Typeable` tries to make *particularly* sure that it can only be applied when the type is completely known, because it's essential for `Typeable` conversions to be safe. Some subtle loopholes in this have been closed in recent GHCs.